# Trocar operador + por - em método refatorado

Tags: c#, refatoração

O Código abaixo tem o objetivo de realizar uma movimentação em um objeto no eixo Y de um objeto seguindo o mouse (o código funciona), veja que o código dentro do `if` e do `else if` são iguais a não ser pelo operador **+** e **-** quais seriam as formas de refatorar este código duplicado alterando somente os operadores da linha (somente o que esta em negrito):

> mousePosition3D.y = transform.position.y **+** (initialMousePosition.y - mousePosition3D.y);

```
private void SwipeContainer(Directions direction){
    if(direction == Directions.Top && transform.localPosition.y < maxTopPosition){
        Vector3 position = Input.mousePosition;

        Vector3 mousePosition3D = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
        mousePosition3D.z = -1f;
        mousePosition3D.x = transform.position.x;
        mousePosition3D.y = transform.position.y + (initialMousePosition.y - mousePosition3D.y);

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            transform.position, mousePosition3D, speedMoviment * Time.deltaTime
        );
    }else if(direction == Directions.Bottom && transform.localPosition.y > maxBottomPosition){
        Vector3 position = Input.mousePosition;

        Vector3 mousePosition3D = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
        mousePosition3D.z = -1f;
        mousePosition3D.x = transform.position.x;
        mousePosition3D.y = transform.position.y - (initialMousePosition.y - mousePosition3D.y);

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            transform.position, mousePosition3D, speedMoviment * Time.deltaTime
        );
    }
```

Este problema de refatoração não se aplica somente a esta linguagem (**C#**) e situação especifica, quais seriam as formas adequadas de refatoração (que seja aplicável a maioria das linguagens como: **C#, Java, PHP, Javascript, C**)

Comment: Você pode verificar a condição apenas na linha em questão. Se só tiver essas opções pode alterar para um `if else` simples. Da forma que está ele vai fazer as duas comparações, mas se não atender nenhuma das duas ele não fará nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aplique os seus conhecimentos de álgebra:

> x + y = x + (1)*y
>   x - y = x + (-1)*y

Crie um novo método e coloque esse código repetido nele, use aquele que tem o sinal `+` e multiplique o troço `(initialMousePosition.y - mousePosition3D.y)` pelo valor passado ao método.

Chame esse método passando 1 ou - 1 consoante queira somar ou subtrair.

```
private void SwipeContainer(Directions direction){
    if(direction == Directions.Top && transform.localPosition.y < maxTopPosition){
        movimenta(1);
    }else if(direction == Directions.Bottom && transform.localPosition.y > maxBottomPosition){
        movimenta(-1);
    }
}

private void movimenta(int direcao){
    Vector3 position = Input.mousePosition;

    Vector3 mousePosition3D = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
    mousePosition3D.z = -1f;
    mousePosition3D.x = transform.position.x;
    mousePosition3D.y = transform.position.y + direcao * (initialMousePosition.y - mousePosition3D.y);

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
        transform.position, mousePosition3D, speedMoviment * Time.deltaTime
    );
}
```

Comment: Sem dúvida uma abordagem muito inteligente.

Comment: Apenas um pouco de álgebra:  x - y não é mais que x + (-1)*y